# AS3 - Highlighted text color

Tags: actionscript-3, textfield

Does Flash auto set the color of highlighted text? For some reason it is some kind of blue. How can I change it to white for example?

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6jnu.jpg

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can't be done using pure ActionScript unless you want to try to write your own implementation of TextField, which I can only imagine would be a nightmare.

Flex allows you to set styles for selected text colors, which I'm guessing is what is being used in the screenshot you posted. Here's a blog entry on how to do it using Flex 4:

http://blog.flexexamples.com/2009/11/07/setting-the-selection-highlight-color-on-a-spark-richeditabletext-control-in-flex-4/

Comment: Yeah. not only that TextField relies on lots of undocumented classes too